# How to analyze Android ANR files

Tags: android, anr

How can I analyze such an ANR file? For me, there's no clue, It looks like Native caused inputManager to be locked？How can I find the root cause of the problem and solve it？The device information and other information are as follows。or are there any articles related to ANR that can be recommended for learning.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Tombstone maker: 'xCrash 3.1.0'
Crash type: 'anr'
Start time: '2023-07-27T11:39:35.310+0800'
Crash time: '2023-07-27T11:39:46.215+0800'
App ID: 'xxxx'
App version: '6.0.0 (9617fa8)'
Rooted: 'No'
API level: '22'
OS version: '5.1.1'
Kernel version: 'Linux version 3.10.73-perf-g14010394a #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 22 15:14:44 CST 2019 (aarch64)'
ABI list: 'arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi'
Manufacturer: 'vivo'
Brand: 'vivo'
Model: 'vivo X7Plus'
Build fingerprint: 'vivo/PD1603/PD1603:5.1.1/LMY47V/compiler08221507:user/release-keys'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 9860  >>> xxxx <<<

--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
Cmd line: xxxx
Mode: ART DumpForSigQuit
Zygote loaded classes=3659 post zygote classes=7640
Intern table: 56680 strong; 3252 weak
JNI: CheckJNI is off; globals=435 (plus 18 weak)
Libraries: /data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm64/libbilicr.88.0.4324.188.so /data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm64/libblkv.so /data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm64/libmsr.so /data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm64/libsentry-android.so /data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm64/libsentry.so /data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm64/libsqlcipher.so /data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm64/libtnet-3.1.14.so /data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm64/libumeng-spy.so /data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm64/libxcrash.so /data/data/xxxx/app_tbs_64/core_share/libmttwebview.so /data/data/xxxx/app_tbs_64/core_share/libqb_keystore.so /data/data/xxxx/app_tbs_64/core_share/libtbs_crash_handler.so /data/data/xxxx/app_tbs_64/core_share/libtbsbeaconid.so /data/data/xxxx/app_tbs_64/core_share/libwebp_base.so /data/data/xxxx/app_tbs_64/core_share/libx5log.so /system/app/webview/lib/arm64/libwebviewchromium.so /system/lib64/libandroid.so /system/lib64/libaudioeffect_jni.so /system/lib64/libcompiler_rt.so /system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so /system/lib64/libjnigraphics.so /system/lib64/liblog.so /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so /system/lib64/librs_jni.so /system/lib64/libsoundpool.so /system/lib64/libvivo_runtime.so /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_loader.so /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so libjavacore.so (29)
Heap: 13% free, 87MB/101MB; 1396003 objects
Dumping cumulative Gc timings
Start Dumping histograms for 1776 iterations for concurrent mark sweep
ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 23.767s 99% C.I. 0.023ms-25.298ms Avg: 4.460ms Max: 249.466ms
MarkConcurrentRoots:    Sum: 4.436s 99% C.I. 0.002ms-6.023ms Avg: 1.248ms Max: 19.839ms
UpdateAndMarkImageModUnionTable:    Sum: 2.764s 99% C.I. 0.503ms-6.711ms Avg: 1.556ms Max: 19.798ms
MarkRootsCheckpoint:    Sum: 646.095ms 99% C.I. 21us-3192.989us Avg: 181.896us Max: 172082us
SweepZygoteSpace:   Sum: 301.296ms 99% C.I. 51us-1088.666us Avg: 170.512us Max: 26536us
SweepMallocSpace:   Sum: 205.587ms 99% C.I. 2us-297.764us Avg: 57.879us Max: 2536us
ZygoteModUnionClearCards:   Sum: 203.347ms 99% C.I. 15us-258.312us Avg: 57.540us Max: 2222us
ScanGrayZygoteSpaceObjects: Sum: 188.955ms 99% C.I. 17us-737.375us Avg: 106.935us Max: 4036us
MarkNonThreadRoots: Sum: 179.174ms 99% C.I. 14us-332us Avg: 50.443us Max: 5903us
ImageModUnionClearCards:    Sum: 168.810ms 99% C.I. 15us-183us Avg: 47.525us Max: 2918us
FinishPhase:    Sum: 113.522ms 99% C.I. 25us-305.999us Avg: 63.920us Max: 3719us
MarkAllocStackAsLive:   Sum: 107.174ms 99% C.I. 16us-361.999us Avg: 60.345us Max: 4192us
SweepSystemWeaks:   Sum: 106.707ms 99% C.I. 11us-236.571us Avg: 60.082us Max: 1353us
ReMarkRoots:    Sum: 81.236ms 99% C.I. 10us-352.999us Avg: 45.740us Max: 1110us
SwapBitmaps:    Sum: 72.687ms 99% C.I. 4us-244.499us Avg: 40.927us Max: 1036us
ScanGrayImageSpaceObjects:  Sum: 68.243ms 99% C.I. 13us-185.333us Avg: 38.425us Max: 1839us
(Paused)ScanGrayImageSpaceObjects:  Sum: 64.070ms 99% C.I. 13us-252.999us Avg: 36.075us Max: 796us
(Paused)ScanGrayZygoteSpaceObjects: Sum: 53.222ms 99% C.I. 11us-136.892us Avg: 30.119us Max: 1251us
SweepLargeObjects:  Sum: 34.131ms 99% C.I. 7us-102.999us Avg: 19.217us Max: 2439us
AllocSpaceClearCards:   Sum: 30.841ms 99% C.I. 0.250us-49.841us Avg: 4.341us Max: 3460us
EnqueueFinalizerReferences: Sum: 29.901ms 99% C.I. 1us-75.749us Avg: 16.836us Max: 440us
ScanGrayAllocSpaceObjects:  Sum: 27.780ms 99% C.I. 0.251us-86.200us Avg: 7.820us Max: 2166us
MarkingPhase:   Sum: 25.488ms 99% C.I. 2us-93.285us Avg: 14.351us Max: 1151us
InitializePhase:    Sum: 24.927ms 99% C.I. 0.252us-101.999us Avg: 14.035us Max: 3975us
(Paused)PausePhase: Sum: 17.349ms 99% C.I. 3us-88.999us Avg: 9.768us Max: 503us
ProcessCards:   Sum: 17.193ms 99% C.I. 1us-49.834us Avg: 4.840us Max: 365us
PreCleanCards:  Sum: 14.109ms 99% C.I. 2us-49.975us Avg: 7.944us Max: 1418us
RevokeAllThreadLocalAllocationStacks:   Sum: 11.164ms 99% C.I. 1us-49.862us Avg: 6.286us Max: 655us
ReclaimPhase:   Sum: 8.995ms 99% C.I. 1us-49.834us Avg: 5.064us Max: 1370us
(Paused)ScanGrayAllocSpaceObjects:  Sum: 8.059ms 99% C.I. 0.250us-49.834us Avg: 2.268us Max: 405us
Sweep:  Sum: 5.594ms 99% C.I. 0.250us-49.806us Avg: 3.149us Max: 228us
ProcessReferences:  Sum: 5.553ms 99% C.I. 1us-49.806us Avg: 3.126us Max: 200us
BindBitmaps:    Sum: 5.462ms 99% C.I. 0.250us-44us Avg: 3.075us Max: 44us
MarkRoots:  Sum: 4.377ms 99% C.I. 0.250us-49.778us Avg: 2.464us Max: 480us
RecursiveMark:  Sum: 4.153ms 99% C.I. 0.250us-49.778us Avg: 2.338us Max: 61us
SwapStacks: Sum: 1.131ms 99% C.I. 250ns-49778ns Avg: 636ns Max: 160000ns
UnBindBitmaps:  Sum: 778us 99% C.I. 250ns-26000ns Avg: 438ns Max: 26000ns
FindDefaultSpaceBitmap: Sum: 259us 99% C.I. 250ns-22000ns Avg: 145ns Max: 22000ns
(Paused)ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 75us 99% C.I. 250ns-49000ns Avg: 42ns Max: 49000ns
PreSweepingGcVerification:  Sum: 58us 99% C.I. 250ns-49778ns Avg: 32ns Max: 54000ns
Done Dumping histograms 
concurrent mark sweep paused:   Sum: 253.796ms 99% C.I. 48us-797.647us Avg: 142.903us Max: 2450us
concurrent mark sweep total time: 33.804s mean time: 19.034ms
concurrent mark sweep freed: 927591 objects with total size 60MB
concurrent mark sweep throughput: 27440.3/s / 1836KB/s
Start Dumping histograms for 6 iterations for partial concurrent mark sweep
ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 1.331s 99% C.I. 0.046ms-299.968ms Avg: 73.952ms Max: 303.478ms
SweepMallocSpace:   Sum: 172.611ms 99% C.I. 0.034ms-95.360ms Avg: 14.384ms Max: 98.869ms
ScanGrayAllocSpaceObjects:  Sum: 122.213ms 99% C.I. 0.020ms-45.056ms Avg: 10.184ms Max: 45.852ms
MarkRootsCheckpoint:    Sum: 100.368ms 99% C.I. 1.166ms-24.147ms Avg: 8.364ms Max: 24.147ms
UpdateAndMarkImageModUnionTable:    Sum: 31.166ms 99% C.I. 1.270ms-13.090ms Avg: 5.194ms Max: 13.090ms
(Paused)ScanGrayObjects:    Sum: 23.367ms 99% C.I. 0.597ms-6.561ms Avg: 3.894ms Max: 6.565ms
MarkConcurrentRoots:    Sum: 19.500ms 99% C.I. 0.005ms-4.675ms Avg: 1.625ms Max: 4.707ms
SweepLargeObjects:  Sum: 11.751ms 99% C.I. 0.071ms-8.975ms Avg: 1.958ms Max: 9.145ms
ReMarkRoots:    Sum: 10.037ms 99% C.I. 1.002ms-3.488ms Avg: 1.672ms Max: 3.502ms
ReclaimPhase:   Sum: 8.862ms 99% C.I. 0.003ms-8.636ms Avg: 1.477ms Max: 8.817ms
MarkAllocStackAsLive:   Sum: 8.262ms 99% C.I. 0.146ms-2.689ms Avg: 1.377ms Max: 2.695ms
AllocSpaceClearCards:   Sum: 5.191ms 99% C.I. 6us-1164us Avg: 216.291us Max: 1166us
UpdateAndMarkZygoteModUnionTable:   Sum: 1.725ms 99% C.I. 140us-352us Avg: 287.500us Max: 352us
FinishPhase:    Sum: 1.654ms 99% C.I. 78us-403us Avg: 275.666us Max: 403us
ScanGrayImageSpaceObjects:  Sum: 1.525ms 99% C.I. 21us-1030.500us Avg: 254.166us Max: 1044us
SweepSystemWeaks:   Sum: 1.297ms 99% C.I. 53us-430us Avg: 216.166us Max: 430us
MarkNonThreadRoots: Sum: 946us 99% C.I. 22us-222us Avg: 78.833us Max: 222us
EnqueueFinalizerReferences: Sum: 714us 99% C.I. 23us-274us Avg: 119us Max: 274us
RevokeAllThreadLocalAllocationStacks:   Sum: 627us 99% C.I. 17us-271us Avg: 104.500us Max: 271us
ImageModUnionClearCards:    Sum: 522us 99% C.I. 24us-79us Avg: 43.500us Max: 79us
ZygoteModUnionClearCards:   Sum: 346us 99% C.I. 18us-41us Avg: 28.833us Max: 41us
ProcessReferences:  Sum: 197us 99% C.I. 7us-55us Avg: 32.833us Max: 55us
ScanGrayZygoteSpaceObjects: Sum: 132us 99% C.I. 16us-34us Avg: 22us Max: 34us
SwapBitmaps:    Sum: 115us 99% C.I. 6us-64us Avg: 19.166us Max: 64us
MarkingPhase:   Sum: 66us 99% C.I. 8us-13us Avg: 11us Max: 13us
(Paused)PausePhase: Sum: 62us 99% C.I. 8us-13us Avg: 10.333us Max: 13us
PreCleanCards:  Sum: 56us 99% C.I. 7us-14us Avg: 9.333us Max: 14us
ProcessCards:   Sum: 44us 99% C.I. 1us-6us Avg: 3.666us Max: 6us
Sweep:  Sum: 28us 99% C.I. 3us-7us Avg: 4.666us Max: 7us
MarkRoots:  Sum: 19us 99% C.I. 1us-4us Avg: 3.166us Max: 4us
BindBitmaps:    Sum: 10us 99% C.I. 1us-3us Avg: 1.666us Max: 3us
InitializePhase:    Sum: 8us 99% C.I. 1us-3us Avg: 1.333us Max: 3us
RecursiveMark:  Sum: 7us 99% C.I. 0.250us-2us Avg: 1.166us Max: 2us
UnBindBitmaps:  Sum: 3us 99% C.I. 250ns-1000ns Avg: 500ns Max: 1000ns
(Paused)ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 2us 99% C.I. 250ns-1000ns Avg: 333ns Max: 1000ns
SweepZygoteSpace:   Sum: 1us 99% C.I. 250ns-1000ns Avg: 166ns Max: 1000ns
FindDefaultSpaceBitmap: Sum: 0 99% C.I. 0ns-0ns Avg: 0ns Max: 0ns
Done Dumping histograms 
partial concurrent mark sweep paused:   Sum: 192.167ms 99% C.I. 2.190ms-155.680ms Avg: 32.027ms Max: 158.684ms
partial concurrent mark sweep total time: 1.854s mean time: 309.097ms
partial concurrent mark sweep freed: 813430 objects with total size 54MB
partial concurrent mark sweep throughput: 438743/s / 29MB/s
Start Dumping histograms for 22 iterations for sticky concurrent mark sweep
ScanGrayAllocSpaceObjects:  Sum: 578.933ms 99% C.I. 0.012ms-43.040ms Avg: 6.578ms Max: 44.186ms
ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 468.053ms 99% C.I. 0.010ms-70.448ms Avg: 5.707ms Max: 80.398ms
FreeList:   Sum: 307.766ms 99% C.I. 4.164us-6330us Avg: 297.358us Max: 41977us
MarkRootsCheckpoint:    Sum: 279.842ms 99% C.I. 0.127ms-62.255ms Avg: 6.360ms Max: 73.930ms
(Paused)ScanGrayObjects:    Sum: 69.159ms 99% C.I. 0.500ms-9.944ms Avg: 4.322ms Max: 9.991ms
SweepArray: Sum: 68.266ms 99% C.I. 0.048ms-12.714ms Avg: 3.103ms Max: 12.811ms
MarkConcurrentRoots:    Sum: 61.822ms 99% C.I. 0.004ms-5.456ms Avg: 1.405ms Max: 5.479ms
ScanGrayImageSpaceObjects:  Sum: 59.708ms 99% C.I. 0.022ms-10.795ms Avg: 1.357ms Max: 12.421ms
ReMarkRoots:    Sum: 51.471ms 99% C.I. 0.158ms-9.493ms Avg: 2.339ms Max: 9.800ms
AllocSpaceClearCards:   Sum: 20.390ms 99% C.I. 8us-2427.999us Avg: 231.704us Max: 2951us
(Paused)ScanGrayImageSpaceObjects:  Sum: 6.346ms 99% C.I. 0.040ms-2.162ms Avg: 1.057ms Max: 2.162ms
MarkingPhase:   Sum: 6.265ms 99% C.I. 141us-1223us Avg: 284.772us Max: 1285us
MarkNonThreadRoots: Sum: 4.932ms 99% C.I. 18us-1245.999us Avg: 112.090us Max: 1390us
ResetStack: Sum: 4.814ms 99% C.I. 19us-1056us Avg: 218.818us Max: 1069us
SweepSystemWeaks:   Sum: 4.509ms 99% C.I. 11us-894.999us Avg: 204.954us Max: 908us
ImageModUnionClearCards:    Sum: 3.101ms 99% C.I. 21us-522.999us Avg: 70.477us Max: 564us
FinishPhase:    Sum: 2.177ms 99% C.I. 14us-778.499us Avg: 98.954us Max: 828us
ScanGrayZygoteSpaceObjects: Sum: 1.841ms 99% C.I. 15us-451.999us Avg: 57.531us Max: 452us
EnqueueFinalizerReferences: Sum: 1.763ms 99% C.I. 4us-358us Avg: 80.136us Max: 358us
ZygoteModUnionClearCards:   Sum: 1.724ms 99% C.I. 19us-224us Avg: 53.875us Max: 224us
RevokeAllThreadLocalAllocationStacks:   Sum: 1.655ms 99% C.I. 7us-239us Avg: 75.227us Max: 249us
(Paused)ScanGrayAllocSpaceObjects:  Sum: 1.612ms 99% C.I. 21us-519us Avg: 134.333us Max: 519us
(Paused)PausePhase: Sum: 278us 99% C.I. 7us-29us Avg: 12.636us Max: 29us
(Paused)ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 267us 99% C.I. 0.261us-203us Avg: 12.136us Max: 203us
PreCleanCards:  Sum: 210us 99% C.I. 4us-15us Avg: 9.545us Max: 15us
ProcessCards:   Sum: 186us 99% C.I. 2us-9us Avg: 4.227us Max: 9us
ProcessReferences:  Sum: 143us 99% C.I. 1us-26us Avg: 6.500us Max: 26us
ReclaimPhase:   Sum: 111us 99% C.I. 3us-9us Avg: 5.045us Max: 9us
SwapBitmaps:    Sum: 80us 99% C.I. 1us-7us Avg: 3.636us Max: 7us
MarkRoots:  Sum: 71us 99% C.I. 1us-5us Avg: 3.227us Max: 5us
InitializePhase:    Sum: 67us 99% C.I. 1us-11us Avg: 3.045us Max: 11us
BindBitmaps:    Sum: 43us 99% C.I. 1us-5us Avg: 1.954us Max: 5us
UnBindBitmaps:  Sum: 32us 99% C.I. 0.250us-2us Avg: 1.454us Max: 2us
SwapStacks: Sum: 22us 99% C.I. 0.250us-4us Avg: 1us Max: 4us
RecordFree: Sum: 15us 99% C.I. 250ns-2000ns Avg: 681ns Max: 2000ns
FindDefaultSpaceBitmap: Sum: 14us 99% C.I. 250ns-4000ns Avg: 636ns Max: 4000ns
ForwardSoftReferences:  Sum: 12us 99% C.I. 250ns-3000ns Avg: 750ns Max: 3000ns
PreSweepingGcVerification:  Sum: 1us 99% C.I. 250ns-1000ns Avg: 45ns Max: 1000ns
Done Dumping histograms 
sticky concurrent mark sweep paused:    Sum: 178.956ms 99% C.I. 0.465ms-17.127ms Avg: 8.134ms Max: 17.127ms
sticky concurrent mark sweep total time: 2.007s mean time: 91.259ms
sticky concurrent mark sweep freed: 1031757 objects with total size 81MB
sticky concurrent mark sweep throughput: 514079/s / 40MB/s
Total time spent in GC: 37.667s
Mean GC size throughput: 4MB/s
Mean GC object throughput: 74674.2 objects/s
Total number of allocations 4208775
Total bytes allocated 238MB
Free memory 14MB
Free memory until GC 14MB
Free memory until OOME 424MB
Total memory 101MB
Max memory 512MB
Total mutator paused time: 624.919ms
Total time waiting for GC to complete: 2.069ms

DALVIK THREADS (128):
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=1 obj=0x75244fa8 self=0x5597fc7330
  | sysTid=9860 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb794be80
  | state=S schedstat=( 2160044246 772827040 4090 ) utm=164 stm=52 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fc5b7d000-0x7fc5b7f000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/9860/stack)
  native: #00 pc 0005f124  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  native: #01 pc 000692f4  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+100)
  native: #02 pc 000278c8  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+164)
  native: #03 pc 0002831c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState15waitForResponseEPNS_6ParcelEPi+112)
  native: #04 pc 00028590  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState8transactEijRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j+176)
  native: #05 pc 00020210  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android8BpBinder8transactEjRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j+64)
  native: #06 pc 000dfee4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  native: #07 pc 012fbd80  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+212)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
  at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.registerInputDevicesChangedListener(IInputManager.java:658)
  at android.hardware.input.InputManager.populateInputDevicesLocked(InputManager.java:691)
  at android.hardware.input.InputManager.getInputDeviceIds(InputManager.java:269)
  - locked
```

Comment: Simply read the logs

Comment: Look at https://techblogs.42gears.com/different-ways-of-analyzing-anr-in-android/ Perhaps the traces.txt file will give you some hints.

Comment: Also check out troubleshooting tips here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr